# Firestore Array of Document References

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure of my Firestore database:

```
products:{ // Collection
    procuct_1: { // Document
       title:"",
       url:""

videos:{ // Collection
    video_1:{ // Document
       title:"",
       products:{ // Array of references 
            0: "/products/product_1,
            1: "/products/product_2
```

I would like to be able from Array field in **Videos Collection** to get Document References to **Products collection** in order to get values of some fields of this collection (ex. title of product).

For the moment I use this code:

```
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore
            .collection("videos")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

                        Map<String, Object> map = documentSnapshot.getData();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()){
                            if (entry.getKey().equals("products")){
                               textView.setText(entry.getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }
```

But entry.getValue().toString(), returns me such array:

```
[com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@451d5ae8,

com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@e28cd0c]
```

Any suggestions how I can get any field of Product collection from this Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("videos")
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                List<String> products = (List<String>) document.get("products");
                for (String product : products) {
                    Log.d("TAG", product);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The output will be:

```
/products/product_1
/products/product_2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting an error _java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map_ on this line of code `Map<String, Object> products = (Map<String, Object>) document.get("products");`

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I didn't see the brackets in your database structure so I thought it is a `Map` and that's why that error. Please see my updated answer. It works for sure now.

Answer (score 1):

This code allowed me to reach the result that I needed

```
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore
            .collection("videos")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    ArrayList<DocumentReference> products = (ArrayList<DocumentReference>) document.get("products");
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
                        DocumentReference ref = products.get(i);
                        ref.get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                            if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                                                BestBuysProducts best_buy = document.toObject(BestBuysProducts.class);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Title: " + best_buy.getProduct_title());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I see that is working but what you are doing is not a good practice because you are attaching a listener for every iteration of that loop. So keeping listeners for data you don't need to keep it synchronized is wasteful. Please see my updated answer using only a few lines of code.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!